# Apache redirect subdomain to folder, process folder as subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, subdomain

It may looks complicated but I need to change the structure of an existing website to bring it to a more seo friendly level. Current structure is subdomain oriented.

ex: **sub**.example.com/page/var/var2/...

I need to merge all sub-sites under the same top level domain.

ex: www.example.com/**sub**/page/var/var2/...

This part is already working for me using this:

```
# If empty subdomain, redirect to "www"
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ 
RewriteRule     ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

# If not empty subdomain and not "www", redirect to directory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/%1/$1 [QSA,R=301]
```

Obviously, as the folder not exists, I get "Not found" error.

This is the behavior I try to reach:

In the address bar, displays

*www.example.com/**sub**/page/var/var2/...*

but seamlessly process it as

***sub**.example.com/page/var/var2/...*

Any idea with htaccess ?

Comment: Where is `/page/var/var2/` actually located? Or is the php detecting the domainname somehow? We can't really help without more info.

Comment: The PHP is currently detecting the subdomain, that's what I'm trying to emulate with the new structure...

For the /page/var/var2 part, the .htaccess rewrite it as 
?p=page&v1=var&v2=var2&...etc

Comment: You could use the `[P]` flag (P for proxy)

Comment: Thanks @Gerben! It actually helped, but I finally decided to make a PHP script to get the "page" part in order to dispatch the correct content with the "var1, var2... varN" parameters.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.website.com/page.html

RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !oldexample.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newexample.com/$1 [L,R=301]
all sub-sites under the same top level domain.